# Replace Maven Archetype property in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, maven, properties, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create a Maven Archetype for a Java web app and I have some JavaScript files I want it to generate. Is it possible to use Maven Archetype properties in the JavaScript file such that it will get replaced by the defined value at generation?

**example.js**

```
#set( $symbol_escape = '$' )
var name = "${artifactId}"
```

The above doesn't appear to work. I've tried other properties as well. It would seem it just isn't supported. Maybe due to collision possibilities with '$'?

The end resulting example.js file that is created just has the text "${artifactId}" instead of replacing it with the value of the property artifactId.

I'm using Maven Archetype plugin/extension version 2.2.

**archetype-metadata.xml**

```
...
<fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
  <directory>src/main/javascript</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*.js</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

JS Path: src/main/javascript/my/package/name/example.js

Comment: Maybe your javascript should go in `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/javascript`

Answer (score 1):

You should add a

```
<build>
 ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.js</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
 ...
```

in your pom.xml